# how to name a Master on a raspberry

Tags: raspberry-pi, operating-system, naming

I've a simply question.
I need to build a MASTER for a raspberry, so i need to make an image of my OS with my own configuration and some specific software installed on it.
Afterwards we must deploy this MASTER in production.

So i need to name this MASTER release like MASTER v1.0.0, to have the possibility to check it simply in production like a command or in a file (the best way is like a command i think)

My question is , what is the best practice to do it. can i modify the file /etc/os-release or something like that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a full control on the OS image you are creating - what stops you to add a file into a predefined location and have your version and other meta-data there, or even make that available as environment variable,  and then you can check it with the script/command?